# How do I open a new buffer without opening it in a split?

Tags: buffers, split

I know I can use `:new` to open a new buffer in a split window (defined by `set splitbelow` and `set splitright`).

But how can I just open a new, empty buffer without opening it in a split?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `:enew`. See [`:h :enew`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:enew):

> Edit a new, unnamed buffer.  This fails when changes
>               have been made to the current buffer, unless 'hidden'
>               is set or 'autowriteall' is set and the file can be
>               written.

And you can use `:enew!` to discard unsaved changes in the current buffer.

Answer (score 5):

Vim also offers `:tabnew`, which opens a new, unnamed buffer in a new tab allows you to easily switch between buffers (tabs) using `gt` and `gT`. This consumes the full width of the editor, albeit, technically in a different window (in a different tab).

Corrected from romainl's comment

Comment: Buffer != Tabs (!). Try both `:enew` and `:tabe` while you have a file that you have not saved. However I still upvote this, as it is the tab equivalent to :enew

Comment: `:tabnew` is the tab page equivalent of `:enew`.

Comment: Thanks, @romainl! Actually, though `:tabe` with no argument behaves the same.

Comment: A side effect. Never bet on side effects.

Comment: @romainl :-) For a script, yes; but for everyday use? I'd prefer using a smaller subset of commands --- so that I can remember them all.